# How do I make the page move to another by a single click in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game and I wonder how to make the homepage move to the actual game by a single click.

This is the code for the homepage

```
from graphics import*
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
brown = (120, 70, 23)
red = (255,0,0)

def writeName1(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 60) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, black) #black text
    textpos = (145, 60)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    
def writeName2(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 90) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, black) #black text
    textpos = (100,120)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()

def writeClick(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 25) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, black) #black text
    textpos = (160,350)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text

    
def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Kill The Zombie') #the title of the game
    background = pygame.image.load('ruined.png') #import the background image
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3') #the background music 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background

    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    drawIntro(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
              
        drawObject(background, 0, 0) #display the background
        writeClick('CLICK TO START')
        
        writeName1('KILL THE') #Name of the game 1

        writeName2('ZOMBIE') #Name of the game 2

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()

       

initGame()
runGame()
```

**and this is the actual game**

```
from graphics import* 
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep
import homepage


#BLACK = (0, 0, 0) used when set up 
padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
zombieImage = ['arm1.png', 'arm2.png', 'face1.png', 'face3.png', \
               'face4.png', 'foot.png', 'leg1.png', 'leg2.png', 'zombie1.png', \
               'zombie2.png', 'zombie3.png', 'zombie4.png'] #the image of the zombie 
zombieSound = ['zombieeffect1.wav', 'zombieeffect2.wav', 'zombieeffect3.wav'] #the sound effect when the zombie is killed
black = (0,0,0)

homepage.initGame() #import homepage 
homepage.runGame()

#records the killed zombies 
def writeScore(count):
    global gamePad
    font = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 20) #font with size 20 
    text = font.render('Killed Zombies: ' + str(count), True, (255, 255, 255)) #the text
    gamePad.blit(text, (20,10)) #placed on the left top 

#the number of the zombies passed 
def writePassed(count):
    global gamePad
    font = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 20)
    text = font.render('Passed Zombies: ' + str(count), True, (255, 255, 255)) #the score 'Passed Zombies: ' 
    gamePad.blit(text, (290,10)) #placed right top

def writeLevels(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 30) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, black) #black text
    textpos = (20, 30)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text

def writeMessage(text):
    global gamePad, gameOverSound 
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 48) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0)) #red text 
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (int(padWidth/2), int(padHeight/2)) #printed in the middle of the game 
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop() #stop the background music
    gameOverSound.play() #the game over sound is played
    sleep(2) #after 2 seconds
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) #play the background music
    runGame() #the game restarts

def crash(): #When the zombie touches the soldier 
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('YOU ARE NOW INFECTED')

def gameOver(): #when the zombie goes off the pad 3 times 
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('GAME OVER') #it types the message game over

def win():
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('All ELIMINATED') 

def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background, soldier, bullet, blood, bulletSound, gameOverSound   
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Kill The Zombie') #the title of the game
    background = pygame.image.load('background.png') #import the background image
    soldier = pygame.image.load('soldier.png') #import the soldier image
    bullet = pygame.image.load('bullet.png') #import the bullet image
    blood = pygame.image.load('blood.png') #import blood image
    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3') #the background music 
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) #play the background music 
    bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav') #sound effect for the bullet
    gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav') #game over sound 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background, soldier, bullet, blood, bulletSound 
    
    #the size of the soldier is the size of the original image 
    soldierSize = soldier.get_rect().size
    soldierWidth = soldierSize[0]
    soldierHeight = soldierSize[1]
 

    #the initial position of the soldier (x,y) 
    x = padWidth *0.45 #the soldier is placed in the middle 
    y = padHeight *0.9
    soldierX = 0

    bulletXY = [] #the list of the bullet position

    zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage)) #random zombie 
    zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size #the size of the zombie is the size of the image 
    zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
    zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
    killSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(zombieSound)) #random zombie sound created when the zombie is killed 

    #the inital position of the zombie 
    zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth) #the random postion where is goes down
    zombieY = 0 #it is the same 
    zombieSpeed = 2 #the speed of the rock going down

    isShot = False
    shotCount = 0
    zombiePassed = 0 
    
    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]: #if the event occurs 
                pygame.quit() #the game will end 
                sys.exit() #goes out from the system
                
            if event.type in [pygame.KEYDOWN]: #add another event for the movement of the soldier  
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #soldier moving left 
                    soldierX -= 5
                    
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #soldier moving right 
                    soldierX += 5
                    
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: #to fire the bullet when pressing space 
                    bulletSound.play() #play the bullet sound effect 
                    bulletX = x + soldierWidth/2 #the bullet is shooted in the middle of the soldier
                    bulletY = y - soldierHeight #the bullet is shooted infront of the soldier 
                    bulletXY.append([bulletX, bulletY])
                    
            if event.type in [pygame.KEYUP]: #when the player don't press the button, the soldier stops moving
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    soldierX = 0
                    
#gamePad.fill(BLACK) used when set up 

        drawObject(background, 0, 0)

        x +=soldierX #adding the position of the fighter so it will not go out of the game 
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        elif x > padWidth - soldierWidth:
            x = padWidth - soldierWidth
        

        #checking whether the fighter is crashed with the rock 
        if y < zombieY + zombieHeight:
            if(zombieX > x and zombieX < x + soldierWidth) or \
                     (zombieX + zombieWidth > x and zombieX + zombieWidth < x + soldierWidth):
                        crash()

        drawObject(soldier, x, y) #the soldier is displayed in the game

        if len(bulletXY) !=0: #draw bullet 
            for i, bxy in enumerate(bulletXY):
                bxy[1] -= 10 #the bullet goes 10 up 
                bulletXY[i][1] = bxy[1] #change to bxy

                if bxy[1] < zombieY:
                    if bxy[0] > zombieX and bxy [0] < zombieX + zombieWidth: #checking whether the bullet is collapsed with the zombie 
                        bulletXY.remove(bxy) #the bullet is removed when it hits the zombie
                        isShot = True
                        shotCount += 1 #the score increase 

                if bxy[1] <= 0: #when the bullet goes off the game 
                    try:
                        bulletXY.remove(bxy) #it gets removed 
                    except:
                        pass
                    
        if len(bulletXY) != 0:
            for bx, by in bulletXY:
                drawObject(bullet, bx, by)
                
        writeScore(shotCount) #place the score of the zombie killed

        if -1 < shotCount < 11:
            writeLevels('Level 1') #level 1 until the player kills 10 zombies 
        if 10 < shotCount < 21:
            writeLevels('Level 2') #same 
        if 20 < shotCount < 31:
            writeLevels('Level 3')
        if 30 < shotCount < 41:
            writeLevels('Level 4')
        if 40 < shotCount < 51:
            writeLevels('Level 5')
        if 50 < shotCount < 60:
            writeLevels('Level 6')

        if shotCount == 60: #when kill 60 zombies game over (win) 
            win()

        zombieY += zombieSpeed #the zombie falls down

        #when the zombie does off the pad
        if zombieY > padHeight:
            #it creats a new random zombie 
            zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage))
            zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size  
            zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
            zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
            zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth)
            zombieY = 0
            zombiePassed += 1 #the score of the zombie passed increase

        if zombiePassed == 3: #if the zombie pass the pad 3 times 
            gameOver() #game over

            
        writePassed(zombiePassed) #place score 

            
        #codes before it draws another random zombie 
        if isShot:
            #When the zombie gets shot  
            drawObject(blood, zombieX, zombieY) #import the explosion in the zombie position 
            killSound.play() #play the zombie sound effect  
            #new random zombies made when it gets shot  
            zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage))
            zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size  
            zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
            zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
            zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth)
            zombieY = 0
            killSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(zombieSound)) #random zombie sound effect
            isShot = False

            zombieSpeed += 0.07 #the speed increase 0.02 
            if zombieSpeed >= 20: #when the speed goes up till 10
                zombieSpeed = 20 #the speed is equal to 10 


        drawObject(zombie, zombieX, zombieY) #drawing a zombie 
        
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60) #game play is 60 sec

    pygame.quit() #quit the pygame

initGame()
runGame()
```

I imported the homepage into the game but I just don't know how to make a page transform into another by a single click.
So, I wish that if the player clicks on the home page, it will just move to the game.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Make the homepage a class so you can isolate it's properties and methods
- Init the pygame screen in the main game then pass it to the homepage object
- Call the homepage init and loop from the main game module

Here are the code changes:

In game.py, after `black = (0,0,0)`, insert this code

```
pygame.init()
gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))

from homepage import homepg  # load other module
h = homepg(gamePad)
h.initGame() # import homepage 
h.runGame()  # run home module
```

Here is homepage.py (shortened to show changes only). You will need to use the `self` prefix for class variables.

```
from graphics import *
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

gamePad = None

class homepg():
    def __init__(self, screen):  # pass in screen from game module
        global gamePad
        gamePad = screen
        self.padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
        self.padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
        self.white = (255,255,255)
        self.black = (0,0,0)
        self.brown = (120, 70, 23)
        self.red = (255,0,0)

    def writeName1(self,text):
        global gamePad
        .........
        
    def writeName2(self,text):
        global gamePad
        ..........

    def writeClick(self,text):
        global gamePad
        ..........
        
    def drawObject(self,obj, x, y):
        global gamePad
        gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

    def initGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background
#        pygame.init()  # called from game module
#        gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((self.padWidth, self.padHeight))
        ............

    def runGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background

        .............

#    initGame()   # these care called from the game module
#    runGame()
```

Full game.py file I used for testing

```
from graphics import* 
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep


#BLACK = (0, 0, 0) used when set up 
padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
zombieImage = ['dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png', \
               'dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png', \
               'dot.png', 'dot.png', 'dot.png'] #the image of the zombie 
zombieSound = ['zombieeffect1.wav', 'zombieeffect2.wav', 'zombieeffect3.wav'] #the sound effect when the zombie is killed
black = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()
gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))

from homepage import homepg
h = homepg(gamePad)
h.initGame() #import homepage 
h.runGame()

#records the killed zombies 
def writeScore(count):
    global gamePad
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20) #font with size 20 
    text = font.render('Killed Zombies: ' + str(count), True, (255, 255, 255)) #the text
    gamePad.blit(text, (20,10)) #placed on the left top 

#the number of the zombies passed 
def writePassed(count):
    global gamePad
    font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 20)
    text = font.render('Passed Zombies: ' + str(count), True, (255, 255, 255)) #the score 'Passed Zombies: ' 
    gamePad.blit(text, (290,10)) #placed right top

def writeLevels(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, black) #black text
    textpos = (20, 30)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text

def writeMessage(text):
    global gamePad, gameOverSound 
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 48) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, (255, 0, 0)) #red text 
    textpos = text.get_rect()
    textpos.center = (int(padWidth/2), int(padHeight/2)) #printed in the middle of the game 
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.mixer.music.stop() #stop the background music
    gameOverSound.play() #the game over sound is played
    sleep(2) #after 2 seconds
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) #play the background music
    runGame() #the game restarts

def crash(): #When the zombie touches the soldier 
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('YOU ARE NOW INFECTED')

def gameOver(): #when the zombie goes off the pad 3 times 
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('GAME OVER') #it types the message game over

def win():
    global gamePad
    writeMessage('All ELIMINATED') 

def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background, soldier, bullet, blood, bulletSound, gameOverSound   
    pygame.display.set_caption('Kill The Zombie') #the title of the game
#    background = pygame.image.load('background.png') #import the background image
    soldier = pygame.image.load('dot.png') #import the soldier image
    bullet = pygame.image.load('dot.png') #import the bullet image
    blood = pygame.image.load('dot.png') #import blood image
#    pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3') #the background music 
#    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) #play the background music 
#    bulletSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('bullet.wav') #sound effect for the bullet
#    gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav') #game over sound 
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background, soldier, bullet, blood, bulletSound 
    
    #the size of the soldier is the size of the original image 
    soldierSize = soldier.get_rect().size
    soldierWidth = soldierSize[0]
    soldierHeight = soldierSize[1]
 

    #the initial position of the soldier (x,y) 
    x = padWidth *0.45 #the soldier is placed in the middle 
    y = padHeight *0.9
    soldierX = 0

    bulletXY = [] #the list of the bullet position

    zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage)) #random zombie 
    zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size #the size of the zombie is the size of the image 
    zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
    zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
#    killSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(zombieSound)) #random zombie sound created when the zombie is killed 

    #the inital position of the zombie 
    zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth) #the random postion where is goes down
    zombieY = 0 #it is the same 
    zombieSpeed = 2 #the speed of the rock going down

    isShot = False
    shotCount = 0
    zombiePassed = 0 
    
    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]: #if the event occurs 
                pygame.quit() #the game will end 
                sys.exit() #goes out from the system
                
            if event.type in [pygame.KEYDOWN]: #add another event for the movement of the soldier  
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: #soldier moving left 
                    soldierX -= 5
                    
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: #soldier moving right 
                    soldierX += 5
                    
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: #to fire the bullet when pressing space 
                    bulletSound.play() #play the bullet sound effect 
                    bulletX = x + soldierWidth/2 #the bullet is shooted in the middle of the soldier
                    bulletY = y - soldierHeight #the bullet is shooted infront of the soldier 
                    bulletXY.append([bulletX, bulletY])
                    
            if event.type in [pygame.KEYUP]: #when the player don't press the button, the soldier stops moving
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    soldierX = 0
                    
#gamePad.fill(BLACK) used when set up 

#        drawObject(background, 0, 0)

        x +=soldierX #adding the position of the fighter so it will not go out of the game 
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        elif x > padWidth - soldierWidth:
            x = padWidth - soldierWidth
        

        #checking whether the fighter is crashed with the rock 
        if y < zombieY + zombieHeight:
            if(zombieX > x and zombieX < x + soldierWidth) or \
                     (zombieX + zombieWidth > x and zombieX + zombieWidth < x + soldierWidth):
                        crash()

        drawObject(soldier, x, y) #the soldier is displayed in the game

        if len(bulletXY) !=0: #draw bullet 
            for i, bxy in enumerate(bulletXY):
                bxy[1] -= 10 #the bullet goes 10 up 
                bulletXY[i][1] = bxy[1] #change to bxy

                if bxy[1] < zombieY:
                    if bxy[0] > zombieX and bxy [0] < zombieX + zombieWidth: #checking whether the bullet is collapsed with the zombie 
                        bulletXY.remove(bxy) #the bullet is removed when it hits the zombie
                        isShot = True
                        shotCount += 1 #the score increase 

                if bxy[1] <= 0: #when the bullet goes off the game 
                    try:
                        bulletXY.remove(bxy) #it gets removed 
                    except:
                        pass
                    
        if len(bulletXY) != 0:
            for bx, by in bulletXY:
                drawObject(bullet, bx, by)
                
        writeScore(shotCount) #place the score of the zombie killed

        if -1 < shotCount < 11:
            writeLevels('Level 1') #level 1 until the player kills 10 zombies 
        if 10 < shotCount < 21:
            writeLevels('Level 2') #same 
        if 20 < shotCount < 31:
            writeLevels('Level 3')
        if 30 < shotCount < 41:
            writeLevels('Level 4')
        if 40 < shotCount < 51:
            writeLevels('Level 5')
        if 50 < shotCount < 60:
            writeLevels('Level 6')

        if shotCount == 60: #when kill 60 zombies game over (win) 
            win()

        zombieY += zombieSpeed #the zombie falls down

        #when the zombie does off the pad
        if zombieY > padHeight:
            #it creats a new random zombie 
            zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage))
            zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size  
            zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
            zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
            zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth)
            zombieY = 0
            zombiePassed += 1 #the score of the zombie passed increase

        if zombiePassed == 3: #if the zombie pass the pad 3 times 
            gameOver() #game over

            
        writePassed(zombiePassed) #place score 

            
        #codes before it draws another random zombie 
        if isShot:
            #When the zombie gets shot  
            drawObject(blood, zombieX, zombieY) #import the explosion in the zombie position 
#            killSound.play() #play the zombie sound effect  
            #new random zombies made when it gets shot  
            zombie = pygame.image.load(random.choice(zombieImage))
            zombieSize = zombie.get_rect().size  
            zombieWidth = zombieSize[0]
            zombieHeight = zombieSize[1]
            zombieX = random.randrange(0, padWidth - zombieWidth)
            zombieY = 0
            killSound = pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(zombieSound)) #random zombie sound effect
            isShot = False

            zombieSpeed += 0.07 #the speed increase 0.02 
            if zombieSpeed >= 20: #when the speed goes up till 10
                zombieSpeed = 20 #the speed is equal to 10 


        drawObject(zombie, zombieX, zombieY) #drawing a zombie 
        
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60) #game play is 60 sec

    pygame.quit() #quit the pygame

initGame()
runGame()
```

Full homepage used for testing

```
from graphics import*
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

gamePad = None

class homepg():
    def __init__(self, screen):
        global gamePad
        gamePad = screen
        self.padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
        self.padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
        self.white = (255,255,255)
        self.black = (0,0,0)
        self.brown = (120, 70, 23)
        self.red = (255,0,0)

    def writeName1(self,text):
        global gamePad
        textfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 60) #textfont of the game message 
        text = textfont.render(text, True, self.black) #black text
        textpos = (145, 60)
        gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
        pygame.display.update()
        
    def writeName2(self,text):
        global gamePad
        textfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 90) #textfont of the game message 
        text = textfont.render(text, True, self.black) #black text
        textpos = (100,120)
        gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
        pygame.display.update()

    def writeClick(self,text):
        global gamePad
        textfont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25) #textfont of the game message 
        text = textfont.render(text, True, self.black) #black text
        textpos = (160,350)
        gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
        
    def drawObject(self,obj, x, y):
        global gamePad
        gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

    def initGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background
#        pygame.init()
#        gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((self.padWidth, self.padHeight))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Kill The Zombie') #the title of the game
#        background = pygame.image.load('ruined.png') #import the background image
#        pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3') #the background music 
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    def runGame(self):
        global gamePad, clock, background

#        pygame.mixer.music.play()
#        drawIntro(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        onGame = False
        while not onGame:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
               break

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                  
#            drawObject(background, 0, 0) #display the background
            gamePad.fill((100,0,0))
            self.writeClick('CLICK TO START')
            
            self.writeName1('KILL THE') #Name of the game 1

            self.writeName2('ZOMBIE') #Name of the game 2

            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(60)

#    initGame()
#    runGame()
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment! And it worked but it doesn't change to another page :(

Comment: What is the code that allows the player to click on the page and so it can change to another page?

Comment: I updated the answer to include full code I used for testing